# What extent of trunk carving is acceptable for tree health?

Tags: trees

I'm in central Florida, by the Atlantic. I have a few trees that would make exceptional canvases for tiki faces. What trees should I avoid? I've seen it implemented in my area, but didn't note the type of tree.

In addition, will I need to mind the depth and area of cuts to ensure the tree's health? Will coating exposed areas with paint, stain or lacquer endanger the tree long term (affect aesthetics)?

Comment: In case I didn't make it clear, I want the tree too stay alive, in the ground.

Comment: Wow... didn't see that coming.

Comment: Let me update this so yheres no confussion. I dont care about trees OR your off-topic opinions.

Comment: Saul, I didn't follow any discussion (assuming there are deleted comments). Nevertheless, notice that this is Gardening SE, so some users will feel strongly about cutting needlessly into a live tree and voice their opinion. And in short, whenever you cut, you risk the tree's health and make it vulnerable both short-term and long-term. There is no "safe" threshold.

Comment: A gentle reminder to everyone thinking about voicing their opinion: We have a [be nice rule](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far as I'm aware, there are no trees more suited to this decorative procedure, which is actually the equivalent of serious damage, than others. The living part of a tree, where the xylem and phloem travels (the tree's circulatory system) is immediately beneath the bark, so any cutting which is deeper than the bark, or removes bark, will cause damage and may lead to infection. Ringing a tree all round by removing bark or cutting into the wood directly beneath will generally kill a tree, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're intending to do.

You might get away with carving into a section of bark and trunk with no major ill effects, or you might not, so if you decide to go ahead and do it, be prepared for any tree you choose to show signs of sickness or even die eventually. A word of caution though about the time of year - because trees are very active during spring and summer, with lots of circulation going both ways, there  is more risk of serious bleeding during the growing season than there would be if this was carried out on a tree whilst it was dormant. It's also true that some trees are more prone to bleeding than others if cut at the wrong time, but ultimately, it's your choice whether to risk it or not with any tree, whenever you choose to do it. To answer your question as it is phrased in the title, 'what extent of trunk carving is acceptable for tree health', none, there's always a risk, yet clearly, there are trees with things carved into their trunks which survive.

Comment: I fully agree. I just found in some tiki carving forum that palms *might* be better because as monocots they have the vascular system distributed throughout the trunk. (The parts about infection and likely rot remain the same, though.) Your thoughts?

Comment: @Stephie dunno about thoughts, its more feeling! No and thrice no is my instinctive feeling - grass 'screams' inaudibly to us when its cut, and if you get close to other plants after cutting, they produce different stress response hormones. How's a living palm or tree gonna feel... just because it can't speak, don't mean it can't feel in some way. Its why I'm not keen on bonsai too... But it may be right that palms cope better, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. You took what I asked based on my understanding and applied it to the best possible advice. Had you simply answered based on how it was phrased.... we'd have gone in unrelated circles, which is my impression of this website as a whole. Thank you for having the foresight to compensate for someone who isn't familiar with the topic, doesn't care about asinine debates, and wants a simple question answered. This is how ALL SE should function. Kudos, Bamboo.